# How can I store the int ID of a drawable in an XML TypedArray

Tags: java, android

My goal is to store all the int IDs of certain drawables in a TypedArray, so that I can access the IDs in sequential order. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array
        name="bitmap_ids">
        <item>@drawable/icon1</item>
        <item>@drawable/icon2</item>
        <item>@drawable/icon3</item>
        <item>@drawable/icon4</item>
        <item>@drawable/icon5</item>
   </array>
</resources>
```

This does not yield the int result that I am looking for so that I can later do something such as:

```
TypedArray typedArray = mResources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.bitmapIds);
int[][] t = new int[width][height];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        t[i][j] = typedArray.getInt(index, -1);
        index++;
    }
```

and even later:

```
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, t[x][y]);
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, R.drawable.icon1);
```

Any hint or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if you can do it this way but alternatively you could add an index to you drawable names and load them using reflection.

Comment: Well I could store a string array of the names and use int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("button_%i",
    "id", "your.package.name"); which would then give me an int ID, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution as that type of method call would reduce performance greatly if there are a number of resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your question but this worked for me

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    t[i][j] = typedArray.getResourceId(index++, 0);
  }
}
```

[TypedArray.getResourceId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getResourceId%28int,%20int%29) seems to return the resolved resource id. With @drawable/name entries in the typed array `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), t[0][0])` draws the correct resource.

Comment: That was it! I completely missed that method... haha. Thanks for pointing it for for me.